# Continuous error in module: TypeError: Artist() takes no arguments

Tags: python, class, module

Working through an assignment, and have tried multiple changes to both the Class and the Module but I still am getting an error, "TypeError: Artist() takes no arguments".

The assignment states:
Define the Artist class in Artist.py with a constructor to initialize an artist's information. The constructor should by default initialize the artist's name to "None" and the years of birth and death to 0.

Define the Artwork class in Artwork.py with a constructor to initialize an artwork's information. The constructor should by default initialize the title to "None", the year created to 0, and the artist to use the Artist default constructor parameter values. Add an import statement to import the Artist class.

Add import statements to main.py to import the Artist and Artwork classes.

Ex:

If the input is:
Pablo Picasso
1881
1973
Three Musicians
1921

the output is:
Artist: Pablo Picasso (1881-1973)
Title: Three Musicians, 1921

### If the input is:
Brice Marden
1938

Distant Muses
2000

the output is:
Artist: Brice Marden, born 1938
Title: Distant Muses, 2000

My Code:

```
class Artist:

   def __init__(self, name ="None", birth_year = 0, death_year = 0):
       """
       Constructor to initialize the name, birth_year and death_year to specified values
       default of "None", 0 and 0 respectively
       """
       self.name = name
       self.birth_year = birth_year
       self.death_year = death_year
  
   def print_info(self):
       """
       Function to display the information of the Artist
       """
       if self.death_year == -1:
           print('Artist: {}, born {}'.format(self.name, self.birth_year))
       else:
           print('Artist: {} ({}-{})'.format(self.name, self.birth_year, self.death_year))
      
 #end of Artist.py     

from Artist import Artist
class Artwork:

   def __init__(self, title = "None", year_created = 0, user_artist = Artist()):
       """
       Constructor to initialize the title, year_created and artist to specified values
       default of "None", 0 and default artist respectively
       """
       self.title = title
       self.year_created = year_created
       self.artist = user_artist
  
    def print_info(self):
       """
       Function to display the information of the Artwork
       """
       self.artist.print_info() # display the information for Artist
       print("Title: %s, %d" % (self.title, self.year_created))
  
#end of Artwork.py     

from Artist import Artist
from Artwork import Artwork  

if __name__ == "__main__":
   user_artist_name = input()
   user_birth_year = int(input())
   user_death_year = int(input())
   user_title = input()
   user_year_created = int(input())

   user_artist = Artist(user_artist_name, user_birth_year, user_death_year)
   new_artwork = Artwork(user_title, user_year_created, user_artist)
   new_artwork.print_info()

   #end of main.py  

ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 54, in <module>
    user_artist = Artist(user_artist_name, user_birth_year, user_death_year)
TypeError: Artist() takes no arguments
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Comment: Using the exact same setup, it works for me. Have you defined `Artist` somewhere else?

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: do you have this all in one file? the error says it is on line 54 which is weird. I have tried copying each into its own file and it just runs ok.

Comment: We also expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error. Where are you confused about how they got to those values?  In particular, what is `Artist` at that point?  Print its type and value, as well.

Comment: I had them all in one file. No wonder it wasn't working. I worked on this for 5 days without realizing they all were their own separate files in the embedded interpreter that we have to use for grading. Sorry, I'm dumb. Thanks for all the responses though! Hopefully this really helps the next person.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, please make sure you code has proper indentation, it might be an indentation problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All of these need to be handled in their respective files inside the embedded interpreter. Makes sure to click the drop down menu and select and fill in the 3 files, main.py, artist.py and artwork.py.

I am dumb.

The code works, if you put it in the right places.

Comment: If this was a simple case of user error, then this question is unlikely to help future visitors, so the best resolution is probably just to delete it.